# Generate next Registration Id from database

Tags: mysql, servlets

I am working on a web application. It will have multiple users. I am using mysql as database.

In my application i am fetching the latest id (from the database, using max(id)) , and then generating the next id for the new registration. This approach is incorrect, as the id might change between the time i update an id

How should i proceed?

Answer (score -1):

LAST_INSERT_ID() or AUTO_INCREMENT will be your friends

LAST_INSERT_ID() :

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1, "Hello")
```

AUTO_INCREMENT :

```
INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ("Hello")
```

And the id is auto incrementing

Some **documentation** here :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/example-auto-increment.html